# JavaScript - listen to x click events based on a list of div id's and execute an action

Tags: javascript

I have a list of div id's rendered as context on an HTML template from a django view:

```
list = ['id1','id2',...]
```

**What I am trying to do**

I'm trying to 'listen' to a click on a button with an id from this list(the number of id's is different for each customer), and to perform an action after a click.

**What I tried to do without any js knowledge :**

```
var list = $('#list').val();
var len = list.length;


    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        document.getElementById(list[i]).onclick = function () {
            report.setPage(list[i]);
       };
    };
```

**The results**

I get an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null'
Which makes me believe I'm totally wrong here.

What am i doing wrong and how could i achieve my goal ?

Comment: Might be that the element in question isn't parsed by the document, yet. Hard to tell without a mcve. Where does this javascript live in the whole HTML doc returned by the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick attribute is used with HTML but in JS you need to use `addEventListener`:

```js
var list = $('#list').val();
var len = list.length;


    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
    var element = document.getElementById(list[i]);
     element.addEventListener('click', function() {
       report.setPage(list[i]);
     })
    };
```

More details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener